# GCE startup script: can't find $HOME after exporting in startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a GCE startup script that downloads all dependencies, clones a repository and runs a python program. Here is the code

```
    
#! /usr/bin/bash
apt-get update 
apt-get -y install python3.7
apt-get -y install git 
export HOME=/home/codingassignment
echo $HOME 
cd $HOME 
rm -rf sshlogin-counter/ 
git clone https://rutu2605:************@github.com/rutu2605/sshlogin-counter.git 
nohup python3 -u ./sshlogin-counter/alphaclient.py > output.log 2>&1 &
```

When I run echo$HOME, it displays the path in the log file. However when I cd into it, it says directory not found

```
May 08 23:15:18 alphaclient google_metadata_script_runner[488]: startup-script: /home/codingassignment
May 08 23:15:18 alphaclient google_metadata_script_runner[488]: startup-script: /tmp/metadata-scripts701519516/startup-script: line 7: cd: /home/codingassignment: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 1) Is **codingassignment** an actual user on the system? 2) Does the directory **/home/codingassignment** exist? If no, you must either create a user or create the directory. The startup script runs as a system process and not as a user.

Comment: 1. I have created a service account user with name 'codingassignment' and permissions set to ssh into the vm and run 'tail -f output.log' file
2. When I ssh into the vm and run 'cd /home/codingassignment' the directory is visible but the cloned repository and output.log file is not there
3. when I run the scripts line by line in the vm it seems to work fine, only as a startup script it doesn't, so I set &HOME manually as per this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496155/how-to-set-home-before-startup-script-in-google-compute-engine

Answer (score 1):

That's because at the time when the script is executed, the `/home/codingassignment` directory doesn't exist **yet**. To quote the answer you referred to in the comment:

> The startup script is executed as root when the user have been not created yet and no user is logged in

The user home directory for the `codingassignment` user is created later, when you try to login through SSH for example, if you're using the SSH button in Cloud Console or use the `gcloud compute ssh` command.

My suggestion:
a) Download the code to some "neutral" directory, like `/assignment` and set proper permissions for this folder so that the `codingassignment` user can access it later.
b) Try first creating the user with `adduser` - this might solve your problem. First create the user, then use `su codingassignment` to drop root permissions, if you don't need them when executing the script.